# How to solve deleteById in springboot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

CustomerController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/delete",method = {RequestMethod.DELETE,RequestMethod.GET})
public String deleteCustomer(Long id) {
    
    customerService.deleteCustomer(id);
    return "redirect:/customer";
    
}
```

CustomerService.java

```
public void deleteCustomer(Long id) {
customerRepository.deleteById(id);      
    }
```

customer.html delete modal

```
<!--Delete Modal -->
<a th:href="@{/customer/delete/(id=${customer.id})}" 
        type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteButton" 
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#deleteModal">
        <span class="material-icons">delete_outline</span></a>

        <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h5>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Are you sure want to delete this customer record?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a type="button" id="confirmDeleteButton" href="" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, Delete</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

js script

```
$('#deleteButton').on('click',function(event){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#confirmDeleteButton').attr('href',href);
    $('#deleteModal').submit();
    
})
```

I am getting an error on clicking on delete confirmation button on modal

**Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available**

Answer (score 0):

Missing id in RequestMapping?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/delete/{id}", ....
```

Comment: No.i doesnt seems like a problem

Answer (score 0):

CustomerController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/delete/",method = {RequestMethod.DELETE,RequestMethod.GET})
public String deleteCustomer(Long id) {
    
    customerService.deleteCustomer(id);
    return "redirect:/customer";
    
}
```

The forward slash after the delete solved everything

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).